# Sql Where condition not returning rows specified

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a sql select query that is supposed to return a bunch of rows filter by a where clause. Everything works until I add an "OR" then it doesn't seem to return the correct rows.(Sql server management Studio 2008)

Here is my query:

```
Select @Command = 
'select DISTINCT C.FileID, C.FileName, convert(nvarchar,C.DateReported,111) AS ''DateReported'', 
C.FileDetailsPlainText, CFIT.Level3 as ''InvestigationType'', INV.FName + '' '' + INV.LName AS ''Name'', 
convert(nvarchar,DD,111) AS ''DD'', i.FirstName + '' '' + i.LastName AS ''ReportedBy''
from CaseFiles C 
join InvestigatorCaseFileAccess IA on C.FileID=IA.CaseFileID 
JOIN CaseFileTimeBills tb on C.FileID=tb.FileID
JOIN CaseFileExpenses e on C.FileID=e.FileID

left join Element07a_Persons i on i.PersonID = c.PersonID
LEFT OUTER JOIN CaseFileInvestigationTypes CFIT ON C.InvestigationTypeID = CFIT.InvestigationTypeID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Investigators INV ON C.InvestigatorID = INV.InvestigatorID
where Deleted=0 and IA.InvestigatorID=' + CONVERT (nvarchar(max),@InvestigatorID) + ' and IA.AllowAccess = ''True'' 
and tb.InvNumber IS NULL OR e.InvNumber IS NULL '
END
```

The "tb.Invnumber IS NULL OR e.Invnumber IS NULL' aren't returning the rows it is supposed to return. When I run the query it returns 5 rows, but I know that it is suppose to return more than 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe adding parens will solve your problem:

```
Select @Command = 
'select DISTINCT C.FileID, C.FileName, convert(nvarchar,C.DateReported,111) AS ''DateReported'', 
C.FileDetailsPlainText, CFIT.Level3 as ''InvestigationType'', INV.FName + '' '' + INV.LName AS ''Name'', 
convert(nvarchar,DD,111) AS ''DD'', i.FirstName + '' '' + i.LastName AS ''ReportedBy''
from CaseFiles C 
join InvestigatorCaseFileAccess IA on C.FileID=IA.CaseFileID 
JOIN CaseFileTimeBills tb on C.FileID=tb.FileID
JOIN CaseFileExpenses e on C.FileID=e.FileID

left join Element07a_Persons i on i.PersonID = c.PersonID
LEFT OUTER JOIN CaseFileInvestigationTypes CFIT ON C.InvestigationTypeID = CFIT.InvestigationTypeID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Investigators INV ON C.InvestigatorID = INV.InvestigatorID
where Deleted=0 and IA.InvestigatorID=' + CONVERT (nvarchar(max),@InvestigatorID) + ' and IA.AllowAccess = ''True'' 
and (tb.InvNumber IS NULL OR e.InvNumber IS NULL)'
END
```

Comment: Have you examined your results to see which ones are not there that you are expecting?

Comment: this is very interesting. I changed the query to only select files where e.InvNumver is null, then took it out and changed it to tb.InvNumber IS Null only, and the query seems to keep acting as if I have "tb.InvNumver IS Null AND e.InvNumber IS NULL". I have executed the stored proc to make the changes though....

Comment: Could it be my type of joins? Since tb and e has the chance to not return something.

Comment: Well, that depends. You might want to use inner joins instead of left joins unless there's an explicit reason and a left join